# Url.Action method displays JSON on view using Chrome on Android only

Tags: android, json, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, razor

We're supporting a responsive C# ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Razor views, jQuery, Twitter Bootstrap, T4MVC and other frameworks (I can list them if it becomes relevant to the answer, but they're fairly standard frameworks).

Here's the problem: using Chrome on an Android device (specifically on a Galaxy s4 or s5) when a post is sent from an ActionResult, the browser displays a line of JSON. I know which line of JSON (will post code below), but I don't know why it's posting JSON. Again, this problem is unique to the device and browser already mentioned. Here is the ActionMethod it calls:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [EnsureSessionState()]
    [NavigationRules(RequireSections = Sections.Elig)]
    public virtual ActionResult Code(Elig model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Code"))
        {
            CurrentRegistration.Code = _CodeFacade.Validate(model.Code);
            return Json(new {url = Url.Action(MVC.Start.Consent())});
        }

        return Json(new {section = "Code", view = RenderViewToString(Views.ViewNames._Code, model)});
    }
```

The controller is called "StartController" and when this method gets evoked on the specific devices mentioned, the browser screen displays the following:

```
{"url":"/Start/Consent"}
```

Which is exactly the URL it should navigate to and the URL it does navigate to on all devices and browsers except for the Android Samsung devices already mentioned (there may be other devices we haven't fully tested, of course, but we try to hit all of the major devices and browsers). This issue does not occur when using the default Android browsers on the same devices. It only occurs with Chrome.

It looks like it's just sending the Json of the line below to the view.

```
return Json(new {url = Url.Action(MVC.Start.Consent())});
```

The MVC.Start.Consent() is a T4MVC construction that references the StartController.Consent action method. Is it a serialization issue?

We can hit the back button and the application will re-commence where it left off, but the issue also happens on other controller methods further down the process.

I have searched the web for "Android displays JSON" "Android razor issues" and other variations on descriptions of this problem but have found nothing so far.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Or is anyone aware of any issues with Android and Chrome that could cause this issue on that combination alone and not on others?

Thank you!

Comment: `return Json(new {url = Url.Action(MVC.Start.Consent())});` does not call an action..   `return RedirectToAction(MVC.Start.Consent());` would though

Comment: let me rephrase that..   `Url.Action()` will generate a url based on the controller and action parameters you pass it but will not call that action or return the value from that action.   To call an action you would use `Html.Action()`..  but from the controller, if you want to return the result of the action you would call `return RedirectToAction()`

Comment: Ah yes, thank you - I had forgotten that Url.Action simply formats a url path and doesn't redirect to it. So that method is working correctly and something else is probably taking that string and throwing it to the view.

Comment: Edited to correct verbiage around Url.Action

Comment: it's not clear what you're wanting to do.. are you calling this from ajax?  what is the purpose of return json here?